# Por que a sugestão de edição foi rejeitada?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

A seguinte [sugestão de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/372812) foi rejeitada com o seguinte texto padrão:

> Esta edição altera o sentido ou propósito inicial do post. Mesmo edições substanciais devem procurar preservar os objetivos originais do autor.

Apesar de editar muitos caracteres da pergunta, o sentido e propósito inicial da pergunta foram mantidos. Qual o motivo da rejeição?

Comment: Como a  conversa ficou extensa, foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134306/discussion-on-question-by-sourcream-por-que-a-sugestao-de-edicao-foi-rejeitada) - quem quiser ler ou acrescentar algo pode prosseguir utilizando o link fornecido.